# How do I read a variable from a file?

Tags: bash, scripts

I want to insert in my script a value (string) that I would read from a text file.

For example, instead of:

```
echo "Enter your name"
read name
```

I want to read a string from another text file so the interpreter should read the string from the file and not the user input.

Comment: What does your text file look like? Is the entire file 1 variable or are they `KEY=VALUE` pairs? The solutions are quite different (if it's the latter, Takkat's answer applies, the former Radu's)

Comment: @CiroSantilli it is not crossposted if it was posted by a different user, there is no such thing as a "cross-site duplicate". The only thing that should be avoided is the _same_ question asked by the _same_ user on different sites.

Answer (score 152):

To read variables from a file we can use the `source` or `.` command.

Lets assume the file contains the following line

```
MYVARIABLE="Any string"
```

we can then import this variable using

```
#!/bin/bash

source <filename>
echo $MYVARIABLE
```

Comment: One reason why you might not want to do it this way is because whatever is in `<filename>` will be run in your shell, such as `rm -rf /`, which could be very dangerous.

Comment: Deserve to be marked as answer

Comment: Late to the party, but, no, it doesn't deserve to be marked up OR as the answer. This sources another bash source file which is NOT what the OP asked for. He asked how to read the contents of a FILE into a variable. NOT how to execute another script which *sets a variable*. The correct answer is the one below. name=$(cat "$file") .

Comment: OTOH, it is the answer to the question I asked google and google brought me here. Weird times, eh?

Comment: Great also works for multiple variables! Point of @MarkRibau is understood but I guess that if you right the file in a different script and just have to pass it over its fine and controlled.

Comment: What if I need to use different variable name for this variable in my script? Use `eval` like [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/266630/221755)?

Comment: You can use `sed` to add `local` keyword and make the script a bit safer and not polute your global scope. So inside a a function do `cat global_variables.sh | sed -e 's/^/local /' > local_variables.sh` and then use `. ./local_variables.sh`. Whatever you import in the function will only be available in that function. Note that it assumes `global_variables.sh` only contains one variable per line.

Comment: @Nux great ideia. I added did this (URL is out of the context): `curl -s https://1.1.1.1/cdn-cgi/trace | sed -e 's/^/local /'`

Answer (score 85):

Considering that you want all the content of your text file to be kept in your variable, you can use:

```
#!/bin/bash

file="/path/to/filename" #the file where you keep your string name

name=$(cat "$file")        #the output of 'cat $file' is assigned to the $name variable

echo $name               #test
```

Or, in pure bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

file="/path/to/filename"     #the file where you keep your string name

read -d $'\x04' name < "$file" #the content of $file is redirected to stdin from where it is read out into the $name variable

echo $name                   #test
```

Comment: I dont want to display the variable, I want that this variable should be read by the script for further processing. I have tried awk which reads line by line.

Comment: Ok, delete `echo $name `. I use it just for test. Next you can use `$name` variable for further processing anywhere you want in your script.

Comment: I cant use it anywhere it my script because dhe script doesn't know the value of the variable. In our case the variable name.

Comment: @user208413 The value of `$name` variable is the string from your file assigned using `cat $file` command. What is not clear or so difficult to understand?

Comment: It's redundant to use a seperate `$file` variable if you're only using it once to load the `$name` variable, just use `cat /path/to/file`

Comment: Nothing about this solution answers the question. It ignores his mention of searching for a specific string in a different file, and instead converts an entire text file's contents into a shell variable. Amazing how many voters cannot read...

Comment: One thing you might be missing is that you can do math on the value you've assigned to the variable by using the expr command - this website has a pretty good article on the subject - https://www.shell-tips.com/bash/math-arithmetic-calculation/

Answer (score 21):

```
name=$(<"$file")
```

From `man bash:1785`, this command substitution is equivalent to `name=$(cat "$file")` but faster.

Answer (score 17):

From within your script you can do this:

```
read name < file_containing _the_answer
```

You can even do this multiple times e.g. in a loop

```
while read LINE; do echo "$LINE"; done < file_containing_multiple_lines
```

Comment: or for a file with multiple items on each line . . . grep -v ^# file |while read a b c; do echo a=$a b=$b c=$c; done

Comment: This reads the whole line of a file, not a variable declared within the file.

Answer (score 8):

One alternative way to do this would be to just redirect standard input to your file, where you have all the user input in the order it's expected by the program. For example, with the program (called `script.sh`)

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Enter your name:"
read name
echo "...and now your age:"
read age

# example of how to use the values now stored in variables $name and $age
echo "Hello $name. You're $age years old, right?"
```

and the input file (called `input.in`)

```
Tomas
26
```

you could run this from the terminal in one of the following two ways:

```
$ cat input.in | ./script.sh
$ ./script.sh < input.in
```

and it would be equivalent to just running the script and entering the data manually - it would print the line "Hello Tomas. You're 26 years old, right?".

As [Radu Rădeanu](https://askubuntu.com/users/147044/radu-rdeanu) has [already suggested](https://askubuntu.com/a/367143/18112), you could use `cat` inside your script to read the contents of a file into a avariable - in that case, you need each file to contain only one line, with only the value you want for that specific variable. In the above example, you'd split the input file into one with the name (say, `name.in`) and one with the age (say, `age.in`), and change the `read name` and `read age` lines to `name=$(cat name.in)`  and `age=$(cat age.in)` respectively.

Comment: I have the following script:                                      vh = awk "NR==3{print;exit}" /var/www/test/test.txt  with this I read line 3 from text file named test.txt. Once i get a string I want to use this string as an input for creating a directory

Comment: Change that to `vh=$(awk "NR==3 {print;exit}" /var/www/test.txt)`. You will then have the string saved in variable `$vh`, so you can use it like so: `mkdir "/var/www/$vh"` - this will create a folder with the specified name inside /var/www.

Comment: I have done this way but it still cant create the folder  :(

Comment: @user208413: What error message(s) do you get? "It doesn't work" is, unfortunately, not a very helpful problem description...

Answer (score 4):

Short answer:

```
name=`cat "$file"`
```

Answer (score 4):

I found working solution here:
https://af-design.com/2009/07/07/loading-data-into-bash-variables/

```
if [ -f $SETTINGS_FILE ];then
    . $SETTINGS_FILE
fi
```

Comment: The slides are no longer available.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use multiple strings, you could go with:

```
path="/foo/bar";
for p in `cat "$path"`;
do echo "$p" ....... (here you would pipe it where you need it)
```

OR

If you want the user to indicate the file

```
read -e "Specify path to variable(s): " path;
for p in 'cat "$path"';
do echo "$p" ............................
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#! /bin/bash
#  (GPL3+) Alberto Salvia Novella (es20490446e)


variableInFile () {
    variable=${1}
    file=${2}

    source ${file}
    eval value=\$\{${variable}\}
    echo ${value}
}


variableInFile ${@}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this to get a single variable from a file

```
GET_VAR=$(grep --color=never -Po "^${GET_VAR}=\K.*" "${FILE}" || true)
```

When `GET_VAR` is not found in `${FILE}` it will be blank rather than causing an error thanks to the `|| true`.

It uses `grep -P` which is in GNU grep but not default in all grep at the time of writing this.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me.  The initial $ throws an error for illegal character

Answer (score 0):

This question is a bit vague, hence a lot of the bizarre responses; in fact, some of the answers on this page do not even address the original question whatsoever.

That said, if you want to source (read) a bash variable from a different file, the best solution is always to use a subshell so that no conflicts arise between your script and the file that is being read:

```
WORKING_VARIABLE=$(source /path/script.sh; echo $FILE_VARIABLE)
```

We use this method in [SlickStack](https://github.com/littlebizzy/slickstack/blob/master/ss-install.txt) for sourcing the config file multiple times without conflicts.

If you plan to use multiple variables from the file or have other reasons to include the entirety of the other file in your current script, then you might source the entire file:

```
source /path/script.sh
```

But in non-bash-variable cases, such as the OP situation of wanting to read a simple "string" from a text file, neither of these solutions would work, and you'd have to use a solution that is tailored to the syntax of the code you are trying to read... for example, one of the examples on this page using `grep` or `awk` combinations, or [@thom](https://askubuntu.com/a/367565/935172) solution for reading a given line of a file using `read`.

TL;DR subshells are best for bash variables, otherwise it depends on the syntax of the file.... if you want to save the file contents as a bash variable, try `cat` as explained by [@hellork](https://askubuntu.com/a/1082763/935172).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a file `/etc/os-release` with these contents:

```
NAME="Alpine Linux"
ID=alpine
VERSION_ID=3.17.2
```

To load just the `ID` variable, grep it to a pipe, then source the pseudo-file `/dev/stdin`:

```
grep ^ID= /etc/os-release | . /dev/stdin
printf "$ID"  # => alpine
```