# Using variables stored on remote server

Tags: server, bash, remote

I have, what I think, is a complex task.

I have 1 machine we'll call a server and a whole bunch of other machines, hostX. 
They all run Ubuntu 16.04 server.
Each host runs a simple bash script at startup, but that script currently has hard coded values.
I would like to use variables within that script, but the variable values should be stored in files/a file on the server, allowing me to change values in one central place and affect a host, or a group of hosts.
I'm happy that I'll have to either reboot, or restart the script on each host after a change, that's no problem.
The issue I have is that I don't know how to use a variable from a remote machine, all I can find is info about running a script on a remote machine.  I want it to run locally, but pull info from the remote.

So here's my work flow, in my head.

Host1 boots and looks at the contents of `host1.cfg` located on the server.
`host1.cfg` looks like this:

```
NAME=John
ADDRESS='10 The High Street'
AGE=25
```

Host1 runs:

```
echo server:$HOSTNAME.cfg:$NAME & $ADDRESS & $AGE
```

Or maybe have a central `HOST.CFG` file with:

```
[HOST1]
NAME=John
ADDRESS='10 The High Street'
AGE=25

[HOST2]
NAME=Mike
ADDRESS='30 The Avenue'
AGE=80
```

Does that make sense?

Comment: If I understand you correctly you could just use `rsync` or `scp` to copy the config file over and then use it locally. Or read it with e.g. `wget` or `curl`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8978261/how-can-i-cat-a-remote-file-to-read-the-parameters-in-bash

Comment: You think adding a line in the initial script to copy the remote file to the local host, then reading it on the next line is the way to go?
I suppose that would be quick easy way.  I'll play and let you know how I get on.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with a file for every single host containing the variables, let's call it `host1.cfg`, copy it over at the beginning of the script and `source` it:

```
rsync user@server:/path/to/host1.cfg .
source host1.cfg
```

This will overwrite any existing `host1.cfg` on the host, so updates to the server file apply on the next run. **Be warned** that `source` will execute whatever commands `host1.cfg` contain with no mercy. Make sure it can't be changed by anyone, *especially* if you run the script on the host as root. For alternative and maybe more secure approaches (depending on your setup) see: [How do I read a variable from a file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/367136/how-do-i-read-a-variable-from-a-file)

I like `rsync`, but you can very well also use `scp`, `wget` or `curl` for the task. If you don't need a local copy you can use (thanks to [glenn jackman](https://askubuntu.com/users/10127/glenn-jackman)):

```
source <(ssh user@server "cat /path/to/host1.cfg")
```

Comment: Or, if you don't need a local copy of the file: `source <(ssh user@host1 "cat host1.cfg")`